# How to Override a OnApplicationEvent method from Running on StartupEvent in Tests in Micronaut Application

Tags: overriding, startup, micronaut, micronaut-test

I have a OnApplicationEvent which executes some fancy scheduled code whenever the server spins up. What I want to do is disable/Override this Call for all at least some of my Unit Tests. I am working in Micronaut Application.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does something like `@Requires(property="spec.name", value="SomeSpec")` help?

Comment: Could you explain it in a bit more detail? I tried reading about @Requires but couldn't get it.

Comment: If a bean in your app were marked with that annotation, the bean would only be loaded when the `SomeSpec` test is running.  You could do things like provide a test specific bean that `@Replaces` an existing (production) bean.  There are numerous options.

Comment: I think it works. I added the annotation @Requires(notEnv = Environment.TEST). Now my Application class is not loading but the test are running just fine. Could you provide some link to resources where I can check sample codes to understand these annotations a bit more deeply.

Comment: "Could you provide some link to resources where I can check sample codes to understand these annotations a bit more deeply." - Some relevant info is available at https://docs.micronaut.io/2.5.7/guide/#replaces and https://docs.micronaut.io/2.5.7/guide/#factories.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from pks18 on the @Requires(notEnv = Environment.TEST) helped me.